# Replacing `dynamic_rnn` with `tf.keras.layers.RNN` giving different results

Tags: tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, keras-layer, tf.keras

For a simple `many to one` time-series prediction problem where I want to predict a value given previous 4 values, I am using a code which employs `dynamic_rnn`. I want to replace this with `tf.keras.layers.RNN`. Below is my implementation for replacement

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTMCell, Dense, RNN

batch_size = 32
n_steps = 4
n_inputs = 3
n_outputs = 1
n_neurons = 64

cell = LSTMCell(units=n_neurons, activation=tf.nn.relu)
x_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, n_steps, n_inputs], name='x_ph')

if use_dynamic_rnn:
    rnn_outputs, states = dynamic_rnn(cell, x_ph, dtype=tf.float32) 
    rnn_outputs= tf.reshape(rnn_outputs[:,-1,:], [-1, n_neurons])


else:
    rnn_layer = RNN(cell)
    rnn_outputs = rnn_layer(x_ph)

dense_layer= Dense( n_outputs, activation='relu')
dense_output = dense_layer(rnn_outputs)
outputs = tf.reshape(dense_output , [-1, n_outputs])
```

When I set `use_dynamic_rnn=True`, My loss value is not reduced which means I am making some mistake. Can someone point out the error?

**Edit: Reshaping the tensor makes the code work but not sure why**

I reshaped the `rnn_outputs` from `rnn_layer` and the code is working fine but my reshaping is actually doing nothing as the shape before reshaping and after reshaping remains same. The following code is working

```py
if use_dynamic_rnn:
    rnn_outputs, states = dynamic_rnn(cell, x_ph, dtype=tf.float32) 
    rnn_outputs= tf.reshape(rnn_outputs[:,-1,:], [-1, n_neurons])


else:
    rnn_layer = RNN(cell)
    rnn_outputs = rnn_layer(x_ph)
    print(rnn_outputs.shape, 'before reshaping')
    rnn_outputs = tf.reshape(rnn_outputs[:,:], [-1,n_neurons])  # what is this doing?
    print(rnn_outputs.shape, 'before reshaping')
```

As you can see the from the following print statements, the shape is not changing by after `tf.reshape` use.

```
(32, 64) before reshaping
(32, 64) after reshaping outputs shape
```

How does reshaping which is actually doing nothing makes the code work?